# Map dictionary keys to rows and display its values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of dictionaries set as `props` in my `React` component, like so:

```
console.log(fruits): [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

The dicts:

```
0:
name: 'Apple'
color: 'Red'

1:
name: 'Banana'
color: 'Yellow'

2:
name: 'Pear'
color: 'Green'

....
```

And I need to display their NAMES in the rows, each row based on a respective fruit color:

```
class Basket extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fruits:[],
      isLoaded:false
    };
  }

render() {

        const { fruits } = this.props;
        console.log(fruits)

        return (
     <div className="app">
        <div className="fruit-wrapper">
          <div className="row">
            <Fruit>Apple</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Red 2</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Red 3</Fruit>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Fruit>Banana</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Yellow 2</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Yellow 3</Fruit>
          </div>
            <div className="row">
            <Fruit>Pear</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Green 1</Fruit>
            <Fruit>Green 2</Fruit>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

export default Basket;

---

How can I map fruit object values from this list os dicts and display fruit **names** assigning each name to its respective row color?

Comment: Why do you need the `Yellow 2` and `Yellow 3` cells?

Comment: because there are three values for each. it is just a dummy name

Comment: I have updated the sandbox and used a class component structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-framework-vos13?file=/src/App.js:0-439)

```
import React from "react";

function Fruit({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export default class Basket extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false
  };

  render() {
    const { fruits } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="fruit-wrapper">
          {fruits.map(({ name, color }) => (
            <div className="fruit-wrapper">
              <Fruit>{name}</Fruit>
              <Fruit>{color} 2</Fruit>
              <Fruit>{color} 3</Fruit>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. but can you keep <Fruit/> component? is it any different than mapping to <div>?

Comment: it's important to keep the structure. note the `<div className='fruit-wrapper'`

Comment: sorry, your solution is not working for me. I cannot recfactor from state to stateless component. If you wish to offer a solution based on my initial structure, I'll accept it.

Comment: please refer to my edit. when I add your two functions, I get:    `Line 52:12:  Parsing error: Unexpected token`

Comment: are there not arrows missing in functions?

Comment: plus: in the question, fruits is declared as `props`, inside `render()`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221669/discussion-between-alex-mckay-and-8-bit-borges).